What does it mean when AddressSanitizer prints an error, but no backtrace, and program exit code is still 0?
I am using ASAN on macOS with success usually, but currently I experience the problem that my program sometimes terminates with an ASAN error printed, but otherwise normally. I do not get a trace like usually.
[…] normal program output
=================================================================
==25422==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x000105a0d918 at pc 0x000102572440 bp 0x00016dd31180 sp 0x00016dd31178
READ of size 8 at 0x000105a0d918 thread T8
[…] program exits with success

I compile my code with -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer and debug flags and run it with ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=true;handle_abort=true ./executable.
Since this failure only happens very rarely, I am stumped as to how it can be debugged.
What does it tell me when ASAN omits the trace which normally would inform me who allocated the offending memory, and where it was freed? What can I do to get this information?
This is a 12.6.5 ARM macbook with apple clan arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0.

I am stump as to how it can be debugged -- Does your program log what is being done, so that you have an idea of where the problem occurs?  Is it a multithreaded program?  If so, then sometimes the only effective way to debug MT programs is to produce a log of what is going on before the crash, and then inspect the code from there.

Yes, it is likely related to object lifetimes across threads.

Then it will be much more involved in terms of debugging such issues.  MT debugging is almost an art in itself -- if you don't know what to look for in terms of possible MT issues, you'll never find what the issue is.  You need to know practically every scenario where a synchronization, data race, etc. issue could occur.

What confuses me is that normally i get a complete backtrace of what code and what thread allocated the memory that is being used after freed.

Try using thread sanitizer (tsan) - it may provide some clues as to what's wrong. Also undefined behaviour sanitizer (ubsan)

Also, if you can capture a crash with rr then you can replay that session over and over in the debugger with identical results each time and you can also step backwards in time in the debugger while debugging the recording.

You should show code which leads to this error. I'm guessing you have some global variable with none trivial destructor, so some cleanup is made after main has finished.

Since multiple threads are involved, try also thread sanitizer -fsanitize=thread

Good points suggesting the other sanitizers. rr unfortunately is linux only, but I believe in my case there is a) a circular refcounting going on, and b) a third-party lib's callbacks are still getting invoked after object destruction. I could not reproduces this reliably, hence my question whether the traceback could be made more informative somehow. I think my issue is solved.

Try building your program with -g.

@yugr I am building with -g.


What does it mean when AddressSanitizer prints an error, but no backtrace, and program exit code is still 0?

The most often cause: a race between one thread exiting and another thread hitting an error.
For example, suppose you have a global std::unique_ptr<X> a_global;. This global will get destructed when you call exit, and X that this global used to point to will be deleted. Let's say this happens in thread T0.
If another thread (T1) is accessing this global at any time after exit was called, that thread may report heap-use-after-free (this is likely intermittent -- the timing has to be "just right").
After ASan runtime detects the error and prints the first line of diagnostics, it will then try to generate the rest of the report. But it will not stop any other threads, and T0 will continue running.
While ASan runtime is busy producing the report, T0 may progress to syscall(SYS_exit, 0);. If that happens, all threads, including T1 (which is in the middle of producing ASan report) simply evaporate into thin air.
The end result: process exited normally.

One way this could be debugged: run the program under GDB, and use catch syscall exit (on Linux also catch exit_group).
(Since you are on MacOS, use LLDB and find the equivalent command (which may not yet exist)).
If you catch the system call after the ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free... line is printed, examine other threads, and chances are one of them is inside ASan runtime trying to generate the error.
Using GDB you could then set schedule-locking on and continue only the error-generating thread (which will finish producing the report and exit with an error). I don't know the equivalent LLDB command for this either.

Another way is to simply retry running the program 1000 times. Some of the time you would get no report at all, but some of the time you may get the complete report.
P.S. Some coding styles (such as Google's) prohibit global variables with non-trivial destructors, precisely because such "at exit" bugs are often hard to find and fix.
P.P.S. Another possible fix is to join all your threads before calling exit.
